# How to add a general header to csv export in angular-ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, csv, angular-ui-grid

I would like to add a header row to a csv file exported from angular-ui-grid which displays some additional information about the data (e.g. a title and selected filters). Is this possible?

My current implementation includes the following options. It adds the filter term to each column header using the `exporterHeaderFilter` function, but I have a global search as well, so I'd like to include that at the top:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'projects',
    columnDefs: $scope.gridColumns,
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableGridMenu: true,
    exporterMenuPdf: false,
    exporterCsvColumnSeparator: ';',
    exporterHeaderFilterUseName: true,
    exporterHeaderFilter: function (name) {

        // I would like to do something similar to this, 
        // but instead of modifying each column header, 
        // I want to have a general header above all columns

        var column = grid.getColumn(name);
        var header = column.displayName;

        // add filter term to the column header
        column.filters.forEach(function (filter) {
            if (!!filter.term) {
                header += ' (Filter: ' + filter.term + ')';
            }
        });

        return header;
    },
    // ...
}
```

The result should look something like this:

```
"Projekte (Filter: Lorem)"
"Nr.";"Name";"Jahr"
"49";"Projekt Lorem Ipsum";"2018"
```